# Signing an application with the certificate

Tags: c#, .net, certificate, installation, code-signing

I have a desktop app which has to be installed on some external workstations.
Currently, we have problems with the antivirus software which in some cases blocks the installation process (untrusted app).
Now we have a certificate from DigiCert for code signing purposes.
What would be better:

1. to sign every assembly of the app with the snk file?
2. to sign every output file with the DigiCert tool (but before creating an installer file)?
3. to sign only installer executable file with the DigiCert tool?

Comment: Signing the assemblies does give you the opportunity to detect if the instalations have been tampered afterwards

Comment: I would do 2) and then 3).

Comment: Don't know what you mean by 2), but 1) and 3) are definitely both necessary to work better with antivirus.